# Посимвольный вывод массива Char и ошибка С2440

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, char

Есть задача, написать две функции посимвольного выведения элементов массива char с учетом что функция в качестве аргумента принимает масив и значение размера масива. Текст должен выводиться прописью и в нижнем регистре.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
namespace function
{
void greatout(char par[100]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(par); i++) {
        putchar(toupper(par[i]));
    };
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
};

void lowout(char par[100]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(par); i++) {
        putchar(tolower(par[i]));
    };
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
};
};
```

Выдает ошибку:

> C2440 невозможно преобразовать const char[1] в сhar[].

Comment: а Вы вызываете свой код где то так  `lowout("TEST");`?

Comment: Приведенный вами код компилируется без ошибок. Приведите тот код, который дает ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не ограничивал функции только массивоом конкретного размера, и не путал С и С++.

Попробуйте такой код:

```
void greatout(const char* par) {
    for (; *par; par++) putchar(toupper(*par));
    putchar('\n');
    };

void lowout(const char* par) {
    for (; *par; par++) putchar(tolower(*par));
    putchar('\n');
    };
```

Может, и ваша ошибка уйдет.